# Is there a way to create a one way connection in EJB?

Tags: java, persistence, ejb

Here is my problem. I have an article that has a bunch of keywords/tags (where one article can have multiple tags and one tag can go to multiple articles. Here what I'd like to achieve:

```
@Entity
class Article
{
    String content;
    Set<Tags> tags
}

@Entity
class Tag
{
    Integer id
    String name;
    ... //other fields
}
```

In other words I want to avoid `@ManyToMany`mapping or making my own pseudo `ManyToMany class` (in EJB 3.0). Is there a way for the Article to see a set of tags while Tags don't see the articles they are connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relationship is inherently ManyToMany whether you want to see the Articles from the Tags or not.

You said it yourself: "one article can have multiple tags and one tag can go to multiple articles". There is a "multiple" on both sides.

This means you will need an intermediary join table in the database no matter how you map this into your entity model.

Comment: True, but I don't need/want tags to see what articles they belong to. Is there a way to avoid them having a set of articles?

Comment: Yes, you simply don't add a Set to your entity. You still need `@ManyToMany` on the Set of Tags in the article though. Something like `@ManyToMany @JoinTable(
        name="some_join_table",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="article_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="tag_id")
    )`